# Trying to prove this limit doesn't exist, and looking for intuition on how to decide if limits exists or not.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0^+,0^+)}\frac{\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{x^2+y^2}$$

My first attempt, was just to plug in $x,y \to 0^+$, and well that gives me a negative $\ln$ and a positive denominator that goes to zero "faster" than the numerator. and said that it is equal to $-\infty$. 
After seeing the answer that this limit doesn't exist, I've been trying to prove that it doesn't exist, so I said that the limit is equal to: 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0^+,0^+)}\frac{\ln(1-\sqrt{xy})}{\sqrt{xy}}\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{x^2+y^2}$$
Using L'hopital's on the left fraction (setting $xy=t$) I get : $$\frac{\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{t}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}}=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{t}}\to1 \space\space\text{Whenever }t\to0^+ $$
So what decides my limit is the right side of the fraction, setting $x=y, y\to 0^+$ gives me: 
$\frac{|y|}{2y^2}=\frac{y}{2y^2}=\frac{1}{2y}\to \infty$ Whenever $y\to 0^+$. 

I really wanted to set $x=-y, y\to 0+$ but that gives me a negative square root on the numerator, and been stuck here. 
I would appreciate any help on dealing with this limit, also if you could explain your intuition when you see this limit and how you decide to start to Prove/Disprove will be really helpful. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to do anything fancy or elaborate. The paths $x=y$ and $x=0$ would suffice.

Comment: You have already proved that that limit is $\infty$. What do you think that is missing?

Comment: Thanks alot, guess I overthought it too much. about the $\infty$, I'm not sure but sometimes when we show that a limit is $\infty$ always, we say it exists "in broad sense" (not sure of the translation). But now I get that trying paths out would be the best, could you explain when do you decide to actually take paths? and not try to prove that the limit exists? I get confused everytime I see a limit, my intuition is just "higher power in numerator" means most likely the limit exists (which fails alot of times too).

Comment: @MathLover Yes it answers the question part, but I would love to hear about the intuition part, but seems like there isn't really any real intuition behind it other than trying

Answer (score 2):

A good general rule for this sort of thing is to start by, if possible, graphing your function.  Assuming we accept appropriate definitions for the existence of limits at infinity, the only thing that can cause the failure of the existence of a limit is for two paths to disagree on its value.  Given our constraint, we also have that the paths must lie in the $+x, +y$ quadrant.

Well, let us take a look at what the function looks like:

[image]

It sure looks from this like if we approach the origin along the line $y=x$, we'll hit $-\infty$, but if we approach along either $x=0$ or $y=0$, we hit $0$ (the verification is left as an exercise, if you can't do it by inspection).  So, the limit is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, I'm struggling to see how $x=0$ and $y\to 0^+$ looks like in the graph, if I set $x=0$ and look at that line, I see it hitting $-\infty$ too. (I know it's not but just struggling to understand the graph).

Comment: Look closely at the contour lines.  The function is actually constant ($f(x) = 0$) along the paths $x=0$ and $y=0$.  If you approach along a path that is "close but not quite" to either of these, you will still shoot off to infinity, but if you walk the line exactly you never move up or down.